# Disable vscode tooltip hint displayed by a specific extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

In vscode, when I hover on a python keyword, a [tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1FLy.png) showing the definition of the keyword appear.
I also have pylint installed, and I want to keep the tooltip for showing pylint error but disable it for the python keyword definition. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: It is recommended that you try to use different python language services, and you could refer to this document: [Python Language Server settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_intellisense-engine-settings)

Comment: Changing the language service to Microsoft did the trick, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

By setting the language service to Microsoft in the settings.json file of vscode, the definition of python keywords disappear.

It does not really answer the question I asked, but it is enough for my needs.